# How do I redirect request to another action from one action in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have two controllers

1. `App\Http\Controllers\Controller\StartController`
2. `App\Http\Controllers\Controller\Legacy\StartLegacyController`

When I receive request at my first controller, I check if request contains `version=legacy`

if yes then I want to redirect that request to `StartLegacyController@index` Action

Else I'll process the request in `StartController` itself.
Here's my code from `StartController`

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $version = $request->input('version', 'legacy');
    if ($version == 'legacy') {
        return Redirect::action('App\Http\Controllers\Legacy\StartLegacyController@index');
    }

    dd('OKK',$request->all());
}
```

I am getting

```
(1/1) RuntimeException
A facade root has not been set.
```

[image: Error Description]

I Tried to remove Namespace, even put controller in the same namespace but it isn't working, will really appreciate any kind of help.

**EDIT**

Since `Redirect::action()` not working in this case I've come up with a temporary solution to my problem with as @Ali Mrj suggested

```
$router->get('/start', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) use ($router) {
    $version = $request->input('version', 'legacy');
    if($version == 'legacy'){
        $controller = $router->app->make('App\Http\Controllers\Legacy\StartLegacyController');
        return $controller->index();
    } else{
        $controller = $router->app->make('App\Http\Controllers\StartPageController');
        return $controller->index($request);
    }
});
```

Will appreciate other solutions for the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will do it for you:

```
return redirect()->action('StartLegacyController@index');
```

Comment: this gives me `Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Http\Redirector::action()`

Comment: what if you give your action a url in your routes then redirect to that url? I think this will do

Comment: Yes, I can give it a route and then redirect to it, but the thing is I am trying to avoid URL change.
Just curious, can I get request parameter in Routes Object, I can simply put a condition over there to call the desired Controller

`$router->get('/start', function () use ($router) {
    dd($router); //Can I get Request object from Here?
});`

Comment: try dd(request())

Comment: Yes Tried it, doesn't work with request(), even with app()->request() it doesn't work

Comment: what if you try something like this? $router->get('/start', function (Request $request) use ($router){
        $request->all();
    });

Comment: Dependency Injection did the trick here, so for now, I can use this way, still, I don't know why `Redirect::action()` doesn't work, anyway thanks I'll use this until I get better solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186587/discussion-between-pankaj-jha-and-ali-mrj).